# For loop irregular incremental limit

Tags: matlab, for-loop, data-structures

I have a vector 'A' and based on this vector 'for loop' and 'filter' will look like with constant increment as

```
 A= [1:1:500]'; % random         
for i= min(A):10:max(A);
    filter = A>=i  & A<=i+10 ; % upper limit here is according to constant increment
end
```

Now if I need to change 'i' with irregular increment, how 'filter' will be adapted according to 'i' as indicated in '???'.

```
for i= [(min(A):10:100),(100:20:200),(200:40:max(A))];
    filter = A>=i  & A<=i+??? ; % i do not know how to set upper limit here according to increment
end
```

Its all about to obtain 'filter' based on iterations. since'filter' is defined as

```
 filter = A>=i & A<=i+iterations
```

So in case of non regular iterations how should I proceed?
It can be explained further as if we expand 'i', it will look like as following

```
i= [(min(A):10:100),(100:20:200),(200:40:max(A))]

i =

  Columns 1 through 19

 1    11    21    31    41    51    61    71    81    91   100   120   140   160   180   200   200   240   280

  Columns 20 through 24

 320   360   400   440   480
```

now 'filter' should be 1 to 11 , 11 to 21,.....,100 to 120, 120 to 140, .....440 to 480.

Comment: It seems to me that you should rather use a while loop: `while ii < max(A)` and re-calculate the new `ii` with every iteration. Just a guess, because I don't really understand what you want to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a trivial loop index and then simply indexing to elements of the filter limits array?

E.g. like this:

```
helper = [(min(A):10:100),(100:20:200),(200:40:max(A))]
for i=1:numel(helper)-1;
    filter = A>=helper(i) & A<=helper(i+1)  ; % i do not know how to set upper limit here according to increment
end
```

As an aside, you might want to elaborate on the larger context of this.
It seems this is similar e.g. to histogramming. This manual, loop-based approach might be replacable by something quicker/easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that. But I'm sure there a better way.

```
DefautIter = 10;
OldI = -9;

for i= [(min(A):10:100),(100:20:200),(200:40:max(A))];
    iteration  = i - OldI;
    OldI = i;
    filter = A>=i  & A<=i+iteration  ; 
end
```

Comment: @Bizeau; Thanks but I think this will not work, as I further expanded question above to be more useful for understanding.